# A reverse look up sass mixin, is this possible?

Tags: css, sass, mixins

Does anyone know if the following is possible with SASS

I have an ie mixin:

```
@mixin ie($version) {
    @if $version == 8 {
        html.lt-ie9 {
            @content;
        }
    }
    @if $version == 7 {
        html.lt-ie8 {
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
@include ie(8){
    body {
        header {
            color: beige;
        }
    }
}
```

renders:

```
html.lt-ie9 body header {
  color: beige;
}
```

Now what would be awesome is if I could do something like this:

```
header {
    > nav {
        color: beige;
        @include ie(8) {
            color: green;
        }
    }
}
```

which would render

```
header > nav {
    color: beige;
}

html.lt-ie9 header > nav {
    color: green;
}
```

This might be wishful thinking, but has anyone got any ideas if something like this is possible

[EDIT]

So it's possible! super.

I've update my mixin to:

```
@mixin ie($version,$depth:false) {
    @if $depth == false {
        @if $version == 8 {
            html.lt-ie9 {
                @content;
            }
        }
        @if $version == 7 {
            html.lt-ie8 {
                @content;
            }
        }
    } @else {
        @if $version == 8 {
            html.lt-ie9 & {
                @content;
            }
        }
        @if $version == 7 {
            html.lt-ie8 & {
                @content;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thanks
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need mixin.
Just use:

```
header {
    > nav {
        color: beige;
        html.lt-ie9 & {
            color: green;
        }
   }
}
```